# The program 'gem' is currently not installed, but I installed it with \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Tags: command-line, 16.04, ruby, gem

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and trying to set up my environment for Ruby on Rails 5 using this guide: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html. As far as I can tell, the program 'gem' should have been installed with the command,

```
\curl -L https :// get . rvm. io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

The picture below shows the successful run of that command.

When I got to the "Check the Gem Manager" step: enter `$ gem -v` it said,

```
The program 'gem' is currently not installed.
You can install it by typing: sudo apt install ruby.
```

Should I have started RVM by running `source /home/vespertron/.rvm/scripts/rvm` *before* checking the gem manager?

Will following the prompt to type, `sudo apt install ruby`, be akin to using `apt-get` to install Ruby which the guide warns against?

[image: RVM installed with Ruby]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting, instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I have started RVM by running source `/home/vespertron/.rvm/scripts/rvm` before checking the gem manager?

YES! You need to do this (or restart your X session) so that the correct ruby and gem will be found.  Those instructions were TOO simple.

> Will following the prompt to type, `sudo apt install ruby`, be akin to using apt-get to install Ruby which the guide warns against?

Yes. They are equivalent commands.